# Getting ABAP source code as we see in SE38 via JCO

Tags: abap, jco

My requirement is to display source code of RFC. I have a non SAP environment. I believe SAP stores RFC source in one of the tables. If i know the table and column, I can fetch this info. Can anybody share info on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If i know the table and column, i can fetch this info.

The table is `REPOSRC`, the column is `DATA` - good luck.

(For those reading along, the source is stored in a compressed form that is not suitable for external access.)

If you're not commited to your brute-force approach, you could use the function module `RPY_FUNCTIONMODULE_READ_NEW` - this will return the source as well. Be aware that the source will be of limited use because it will most likely use tons of other stuff from other programs and includes.

Comment: Thanks for sharing Function module name

Comment: RPY_FUNCTIONMODULE_READ_NEW is using Changing Parameters. Now, this gave me opportunity to look at this. Surprisingly, there is no column/parameter name in the result. It is just like anonymous column in SQL. Can you share any material on Changing parameters & the structure types it handles?